# How to use PostgreSQL's string_agg in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

When I am trying to use, it's being treated as a string rather than as a function:

`->select(['string_agg(file_name,',') as file_names'])`

Comment: You are looking for `->select(DB::raw('string_agg(file_name,',') as file_names'))`

Comment: @Uchiha that's what I was going to try. It says `App/Db` not found

Comment: Simply use `use DB;` and I don't think you need to know where to write it

Comment: @Uchiha It is not working for multiple columns. Check this:

```
->select(\DB::raw('posts.*, string_agg(attachments.file_name,','),project_types.name as project_type_name'))
```

Comment: It should be like as `->select('posts.*',DB::raw('string_agg(attachments.file_name,',') as file_names'),'project_types.name as project_type_name')`

Comment: it's generated as `select "posts".*, string_agg(attachments.file_name,, "project_types"."name" as`

Check `as file_names` missing in query

Comment: Guess double qoutation in `sting_agg()` function's needed.

Comment: Ohhh I've found an issue `->select('posts.*',DB::raw('string_agg(attachments.file_name,",") as file_names'),'project_types.name as project_type_name')` Try this

Comment: `$result = self::where(['posts.id' => $id, 'user_id' => $user_id]) ->leftJoin('post_attachments', 'posts.id', "=", 'post_attachments.post_id') ->leftJoin('project_types', 'posts.project_type_id', '=', 'project_types.id') ->groupBy(['posts.id','project_type_name'])  ->select('posts.*',\DB::raw('string_agg("post_attachments"."file_name",",") as file_names'),'project_types.name as project_type_name') ->get();`

Comment: Did you tried the one that I've edited `->select('posts.*',DB::raw('string_agg(attachments.file_name,",") as file_names'),'project_types.name as project_type_name')`

Comment: `posts.file_name does not exist`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96545/discussion-between-volatil3-and-uchiha).

Comment: @Uchiha `: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "," does not exist
LINE 1: select string_agg(post_attachments.file_name,",") `

Comment: Laravel treating 2nd parameter of `string_agg()` as a column.

Comment: Its because we are applying it as try as `DB::raw('string_agg(post_attachments.file_name,",") as file_names')` instead

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "," does not exist
LINE 1: ...fs".*, string_agg("post_attachments"."file_name",",") as fi...
^ `

Comment: I am getting same results even if I user `Db::select()`, guess it's a bug in laravel or either in PDO

Comment: I don't think so error is within writing the query. Missing something that's been not getting by you or by me

Comment: I rather consider it's PDO/Eloquent bug because atleast it should run raw query.

Comment: [Check this doc for pure raw queries within Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database)

Comment: @Uchiha It was escaping issue: `"file_name",\',\'`

Comment: Yes it is I have already told you use double quotes instead of single quotes check my comments

Comment: @Uchiha PostgreSQL accepts single quote for character and double quotes for expression hence double quotes are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

if you have a joins:

```
->select(DB::raw("string_agg(file_name.something,',') as file_names"))
```

and the other case will be:

```
->select(DB::raw("string_agg(file_name,',') as file_names"))
```